# How to simplify or evaluate an integral inside an integral in R?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, indefinite-integrals

I have this double integral to work with:

$$
\int_a^b f(x) \int_0^x g(t)(x-t)dtdx
$$

I am rather very weak in calculus and not sure how should I approach to simplify or evaluate it.

For numerical evaluation I am using R but I believe this is not in a form where I can use the same approach to evaluate the double integral in the following form for example:

$$
\int_a^b\int_0^xf(x)g(t)(x-t)dtdx
$$

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Update: Functions are added in the following image. f(x) basically represents a pdf of a uniform distribution but the g(t) is a bit more complicated.

[image]

Comment: Do you have functions $f$ and $g$? Without knowing those functions, there is not much we can say about this integral. You can interchange the integrals and it becomes $$ \int_{0}^{b} g(t) \int_{t}^{b} f(x)(x-t) dx dt.$$ Sometimes this interchanging integrals can make the double integral simpler to solve.

Comment: @Dan I have added the equation in the question as you requested.

Comment: Regarding the question of calculating this numerically, the typical way to do this (or at least, the one I’m familiar with) is to use an indicator function: a piecewise function which is equal to $1$ inside your domain of integration, and $0$ elsewhere. Multiplying your integrand by this function, you can integrate over any superset of the original region of integration to get the right answer: typically a square.

Comment: @Stephen Donovan I am embarrassed to admit that it went over my head. Would it be possible to elaborate on it, preferably as an answer?